# CSS: centering an element that contains floated elements

Tags: html, css

How do I center an element of unknown width containing elements that have display: block but are all floated to one side?

Basically I have a menu that has a number of items that have display: block (because they need to have proper padding), but are all in one line.

I've made an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKLZ7/1/) where the green menu has to be centered inside the pink element, and the pink element has to accomodate the height of the green menu.

Edit: sorry, wrong example, updated with the correct example

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/

Comment: sorry, I don't see how this comment helps

Comment: It contains how to center a bunch of floated elements.

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`: http://jsfiddle.net/SKLZ7/6/

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Shouldn't this be an answer?

Comment: I guess this question has been asked like 50 times or so.

Comment: @Kyomu Yeah, you are probably right. I was thinking it was more of a suggestion for a different way to do it - the question was to center floating elements

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I guess that makes sense. But if it was what the OP wanted, then would it not be better as an answer? It may not be the one they want, but it is **an** answer :)

Comment: @My Head Hurts - thanks, that works great. Please post is as an answer so others may benefit without reading comments. :)

Comment: @Kyomu point taken - It shall be added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing this with floats, it can be achieved using `display: inline-block`.

So `#mainmenu li` would become:

```
#mainmenu li {
   display: inline-block;
   *display: inline;      /* add this for IE7 as it does not */
   *zoom: 1;              /* support display: inline-block */   
}
```

**Example JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SKLZ7/6/**

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I delete the spacing between the elements? I put font-size: 0px; in #page but in Safari and Opera there's still spacing.

Comment: @DMIL That is the main down point with using `display: inline-block` - it treats each element as it it were `inline` so will place single spaces where it finds them in html (for example, if you wrote two words on a seperate line, they would not be placed side by side but rather with a space in the middle). So the only way to stop this from happening is by putting all your `li` elements on the same line in the HTML.

Comment: That's ok, PHP doesn't mind. :) You've been a big help, thanks

Comment: @DML Dynamic sites are always better :) I've also just found this which might come in useful for avoiding the whitespace in the future: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

I tinkered with what you had a bit. Is this what you're looking for? The green is centered in the pink, and hovering over the green highlights a cyan block. The `float: left` lines are also applied to the same selectors as you originally had...

```
#page {
   background: yellow;  
   text-align: center; 
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
#mainmenu {
    background: pink;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainmenu ul {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
#mainmenu li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
   float: left;
}
#mainmenu a, #mainmenu a:visited {
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;    
}
#mainmenu li:hover {
   background: cyan;        
}
```

​[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SKLZ7/39/)

Comment: Thanks, but there's a problem with this solution in that not the entire surface of the li a element is a link, but only the space where the letters are.

Answer (score 0):

You are using float so other elements will float around it. You have to turn off the float for the rest of the part. Use `clear:both` property to turn it off.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294784/css-container-div-height-floating-div-questions) , you can add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after your list.